# Cannot deploy business network model in to composer-playground?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am very new to Hyperledger Fabric works. I have built a business network and then  I create  the `.bna` file and tried to deploy it to the composer-playground. Then It shows me an error like this.

```
Cannot import an invalid Business Network Definition. Found SyntaxError: Unexpected token (27:6)
```

This is my Business network modal file.

```
namespace org.landreg

abstract concept Address {
  o String addressLine
  o String locality
}

concept DutchAddress {
  o String postalCode regex=/\d{4}[ ]??[A-Z]{2}/
}

enum Gender {
  o FEMALE
  o MALE
}

participant Individual identified by passportNumber{
  o String passportNumber
  o DutchAddress address
  o Gender gender
}

asset  LandTitle identified by id {
  o String id
  o DutchAddress address
  o Integer area range=[1000,]
  o Boolean forSale default=false
  o Double price optional
  --> Individual owner
  --> Individual[] previousOwners
}

abstract transaction UnlockLandTitle {
  -->LandTitle landTitle
}
```

And this is my logic.js file.

```
/*
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

"use strict";
/**
 * Write your transction processor functions here
 */

const NS = "org.landreg";

/**
 * Sample transaction
 * @param {org.landreg.UnlockLandTitle} //transaction object define in the cto file
 * @transaction
 */
async function unlockLandTitle(tx) {
  //Get asset registery for landTitles
  const landTitleRegistry = await getAssetRegistry(NS + ".LandTitle");

  if (tx.landTitle.forSale) {
    throw new Error(
      `Land Title with id ${tx.landTitle.getIdentifier()} is already unlocked for sale`
    );
  }

  // Unlock asset to be for sale 
  tx.landTitle.forSale = true;

  await landTitleRegistry.update(tx.landTitle);
}
```

I search but I was unable to find any suitable answer for my problem. Can someone help me to solve this problem?. Thank you.

**Note:**
After I get the suggestion to change my code by adding transaction instance in the `@Param` line this is how it showing to me in the playground. Can someone give me more solutions to fix this problem? Thank you very much!!
[image]**Problem:**

Comment: I just copied that model file into playground and there was no issue with it. Maybe it's a problem with you transaction processor script file ?

Comment: @david_k I edited the question with the logic.js file. Can you please refer the question again and give me a solution to this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried creating an empty business network and use cut and paste to copy the contents of your file into playground ? Or you could use vsCode and the hyperledger composer extension to help easily find syntax errors. 
The problem is the line ` * @param {org.landreg.UnlockLandTitle} //transaction object define in the cto file` it should be
` * @param {org.landreg.UnlockLandTitle} tx`

Comment: @david_k Thank you very much for the advice.

Comment: @david_k I replace this line but then also it gives me the same error.

Comment: * @param {org.landreg.UnlockLandTitle} tx

Comment: Above comment is what you should replace it with, that fixed the syntax error when I tried your sample

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182978/discussion-between-dwp-and-david-k).

Comment: Also remove **abstract** keyword used with transaction in your cto file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to write **`unlockLandTitle`** in `logic.js` file.

Just replace this line:

```
* @param {org.landreg.UnlockLandTitle} //transaction object define in the cto file
```

with

```
 * @param {org.landreg.UnlockLandTitle} unlockLandTitle //transaction object define in the cto file
```

Comment: As david_k suggestion in the above and your suggestion, I updated the logic.js file by putting the transaction instance in that line. But still, the playground is showing me the error.

Comment: But only in the local version of the playground, it shows me this error but not in the myblumix.net.